# Postgresql update json data with variables

Tags: json, postgresql

I am trying to perform an update with a cursor variable in a previous step, but in a jsonb field, the system returns an error. Contend field is a jsonb type. 
I am doing it as follows:

¿Can you help me please?

Update OPTION 1

```
update test
set
content = jsonb_set(content, '{supplier}', '' || supplierId || ''::jsonb)
where operation_type = 'DEL';
```

*Error OPTION 1*

> SQL Error [22P02]: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json   Detail:
>   The input string ended unexpectedly.   Where: JSON data, line 1: 
>   PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 72 at SQL statement

Update OPTION 2

```
update test
set
content = jsonb_set(content, '{supplier}', '"' || supplierId || '"'::jsonb)
where operation_type = 'DEL';
```

*Error OPTION 2*

> SQL Error [22P02]: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json   Detail:
>   Token """ is invalid.   Where: JSON data, line 1: " PL/pgSQL function
>   inline_code_block line 72 at SQL statement

Answer (score 2):

First, cast the integer column to `text` and then to `jsonb`

```
jsonb_set(content, '{supplier}',  
          supplierId  :: text :: jsonb)
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=2014fd0b1e762e4b980e5e4fff13ce11)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your help.
For Strings works perfectly, but numeric values show an error message.

```
content = jsonb_set(content, '{supplier}', supplierId::numeric::jsonb)
```

Error:
SQL Error [42846]: ERROR: cannot cast type numeric to jsonb
  Where: PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 65 at SQL statement

Is there another way to convert it?

Example data:

```
'{"supplier": 1,"name": "Josh", "supplierId":10}'
```

Thank you very much,

EDIT:
I resolved with: content = jsonb_set(content, '{supplier}', supplierId::integer::text::jsonb)